# Contact form not working - Error: "I don't know what you're looking for"

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form

I've built a [contact form](http://frshstudio.com/#contact) on my wordpress site using html & php that doesn't seem to be working as it should. 
Upon clicking the submit button, I'm taken to [an error page](http://frshstudio.com/process.php) saying "I don't know what you're looking for." How can I get all form submissions to be sent to my email?

```
<div id="contact">
    <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">  
        <h2><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/chat.png" alt="contact frsh studio"></h2> 
        <?php  
            //init variables  
            $cf = array();  
            $sr = false;  
            if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){  
                $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];  
                $sr = true;  
            }  
        ?> 
            <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">  
                <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>  
                <?php  
                if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :  
                    foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :  
                ?>  
                <li><?php echo $error ?></li>  
                <?php  
                    endforeach;  
                endif;  
                ?>  
            </ul>  
            <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Thanks for reaching out! I'll be in touch shortly!</p>    
        <form method="post" action="process.php"> 
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" required="required" data-minlength="20"></textarea>

            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="NAME" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />      

            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL" required="required" />   
            <select id="enquiry" name="enquiry">  
                <option value="refrsh">Brand REFRSH</option>  
                <option value="consult">Brand Consultation</option>  
                <option value="support">Just a Hello!</option>  
            </select>  

            <span id="loading"></span>  
            <input type="submit" value="Holla!" id="submit-button" />  

        </form>  
    </div>  
</div><!-- end contact -->
```

```
<?php  
if( isset($_POST) ){  
    //form validation vars  
    $formok = true;  
    $errors = array();  
    //submission data  
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    $date = date('d/m/Y');  
    $time = date('H:i:s');  
    //form data  
    $name = $_POST['name'];  
    $email = $_POST['email'];  
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];  
    $enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];  
    $message = $_POST['message'];  
    //validate form data  
    //validate name is not empty  
    if(empty($name)){  
        $formok = false;  
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";  
    }  
    //validate email address is not empty  
    if(empty($email)){  
        $formok = false;  
        $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";  
    //validate email address is valid  
    }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){  
        $formok = false;  
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";  
    }  
    //validate message is not empty  
    if(empty($message)){  
        $formok = false;  
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a message";  
    }  
    //validate message is greater than 20 characters  
    elseif(strlen($message) < 20){  
        $formok = false;  
        $errors[] = "Your message must be greater than 20 characters";  
    }  
    //send email if all is ok  
    if($formok){  
        $headers = "From: info@example.com" . "\r\n";  
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
        $emailbody = "<p>You have received a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>
                      <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                      <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                      <p><strong>Telephone: </strong> {$telephone} </p>
                      <p><strong>Enquiry: </strong> {$enquiry} </p>
                      <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
                      <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";  
        mail("alex@frshstudio.com","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);  
    }  
    //what we need to return back to our form  
    $returndata = array(  
        'posted_form_data' => array(  
            'name' => $name,  
            'email' => $email,  
            'telephone' => $telephone,  
            'enquiry' => $enquiry,  
            'message' => $message  
        ),  
        'form_ok' => $formok,  
        'errors' => $errors  
    );  
    //if this is not an ajax request  
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){  
        //set session variables  
        session_start();  
        $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;  
        //redirect back to form  
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is your process.php page?

Comment: @ElefantPhace I've just added a link to it to my OP.

Comment: try capitalizing Location in your header redirect in process.php

Comment: @ElefantPhace did as suggested, problem persists.

Comment: @AMC your HTTP referer is either missing or not correct. What is the name of the contact form?

Comment: @crypticツ Could you explain what you mean by 'What is the name of the contact form?'

Comment: I've edited your post twice to remove `HTML & PHP` from your title - please don't add it back in again. Please see this FAQ, where it is deemed that tags should not be used in titles: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/195862

Comment: @AMC where in the directory structure is process.php located? And where in the structure is the actual contact form located?

Comment: @DannyBeckett It wasn't my intention to use "HTML & PHP" as tags, but as descriptors of the type of contact form.

Comment: @AMC That's what tags are for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be coming from your form action, try this fixed action

```
<form method="post" action="http://frshstudio.com/wp-content/themes/frsh/process.php">
```

and move session_start(); to the top of process.php

and make sure that `<?php`  is the only thing on the very first line of process.php

Comment: I appreciate your efforts here. Again, did as suggested and problem persists.

ETA- forgot maintenance mode was on, sorry. it's now deactivated.

Comment: seems your process.php isn't where it should be

Comment: It's in the theme root? Is there a more appropriate place to put it?

Comment: I've exactly copy/pasted what you suggested above.

Comment: but there is no process.php there. if it's in another folder, you need to specify that

Comment: It's in the root folder right next to all other site files..?

Comment: yep, found it. you have errors in [process.php](http://frshstudio.com/wp-content/themes/frsh/process.php) btw check edit above

Comment: Closer! I now have this error- Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/achenn/public_html/frshstudio.com/wp-content/themes/frsh/process.php:1) in /home/achenn/public_html/frshstudio.com/wp-content/themes/frsh/process.php on line 71

Comment: line 71: header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: almost! remove all extra spaces after <?php

Comment: it's coming for your first line "/process.php:1" tells you the line that has the problem. there must be whitespace or something else that's causing it

Comment: Found it- the entire page was tabbed over; removing that did away with the errors. However, I'm still not receiving anything from the contact form(no on page confirmation, error, or email in my inbox)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25642/discussion-between-elefantphace-and-amc)

Comment: For future reference.. the final solution was to swap:

$headers .= "From: info@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

Try Change All To:

```
<div id="contact">
    <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">  
        <h2><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/chat.png" alt="contact frsh studio"></h2> 
        <?php  
        $message = $_REQUEST["message"];
        $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
        $email = $_REQUEST["email"];
        $enquiry = $_REQUEST["enquiry"];
        $headers = "From:" . $email;
        if($message !== null && $name !== null && $email !== null && $enquiry !== null){
            mail("alex@frshstudio.com",$enquiry,$message,$headers);
            echo "message sent!";
        } else {

        }
        ?> 
            <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">  
                <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>  
                <?php  
                if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :  
                    foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :  
                ?>  
                <li><?php echo $error ?></li>  
                <?php  
                    endforeach;  
                endif;  
                ?>  
            </ul>  
            <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Thanks for reaching out! I'll be in touch shortly!</p>    
        <form method="post" action="#"> 
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" required="required" data-minlength="20"></textarea>

            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="NAME" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />      

            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL" required="required" />   
            <select id="enquiry" name="enquiry">  
                <option value="refrsh">Brand REFRSH</option>  
                <option value="consult">Brand Consultation</option>  
                <option value="support">Just a Hello!</option>  
            </select>  

            <span id="loading"></span>  
            <input type="submit" value="Holla!" id="submit-button" />  

        </form>  
    </div>  
</div><!-- end contact -->
```

One more, I think you didn't have already created process.php